# Prove that $\lceil(\sqrt{3}+1)^{2n}\rceil$ is divisible by $2^{n+1}$.

Tags: number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that $\lceil(\sqrt{3}+1)^{2n}\rceil$ is divisible by $2^{n+1}$.

I tried rewriting $\lceil(\sqrt{3}+1)^{2n}\rceil$ as $m*2^{n+1}$ for some m, but couldn't get anywhere.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to MSE. What have you tried and what are you having trouble with? Please share your thoughts on the problem so that people can give help that's relevant and appropriate.

Comment: That can't be true. $n^{n+1}$ grows faster.

Comment: I feel like this is a duplicate; certainly it's an abstract duplicate.  The core 'trick' is that your value is the same as $(\sqrt{3}+1)^{2n}+(\sqrt{3}-1)^{2n}$, and you can find a simple recurrence relation with that solution that can be used to show that its values are divisible by increasing powers of two.

Comment: What does that mean? By the way, the question is correct. I fixed it before.

Comment: (It's similar but not identical to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226177/using-induction-to-prove-3-divides-left-lfloor-left-frac-7-sqrt-372/226192 but I feel like there have been other examples.)

Comment: Why did you delete your [latest question?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/685426/242)

Comment: I thought it was trivial, but I just undeleted it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $(1+\sqrt{3})^{2n}=a_n+b_n\sqrt{3}$. Then $(1-\sqrt{3})^{2n}=a_n-b_n\sqrt{3}$.

Thus $(1+\sqrt{3})^{2n}+(1-\sqrt{3})^{2n}$ is the integer $2a_n$. Since $|1-\sqrt{3}|\lt 1$, we have 
$$2a_n=\left\lceil(\sqrt{3}+1)^{2n}\right\rceil.$$

Note that 
$$(1+\sqrt{3})^{2n+2}=(1+\sqrt{3})^{2n}(4+2\sqrt{3})=(a_n+b_n\sqrt{3})(4+2\sqrt{3}).$$ Thus 
$$a_{n+1}=4a_n+6b_n \quad\text{and}\quad b_{n+1}=2a_n+4b_n.$$

Thus the largest power of $2$ that divides $2a_k$ increases by at least $1$ when we increment $k$. But $2a_0=2$. This completes the proof.

**Remark:** Whenever $a+b\sqrt{c}$ has a problem, where $a$ and $b$ and $c$ are integers, and $c$ is not a perfect square, its conjugate $a-b\sqrt{c}$ is likely to be helpful.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** The value is equal to $( \sqrt{3} + 1)^{2n} + (\sqrt{3}-1 )^{2n}$

**Hint:** Expanding the square, we get $ (4 + 2\sqrt{3})^n + (4-2\sqrt{3})^n$

This term is clearly a multiple of $2^n$, which we can factor out.

**Hint:** $(2 + \sqrt{3})^n + (2-\sqrt{3})^n$ is even, by the Binomial Theorem expansion.

Answer (score 5):

A succession of hints:

1. Show that $a_n=(\sqrt{3}+1)^{n}+(1-\sqrt{3})^{n}$ is an integer
2. Show that $\lceil(\sqrt{3}+1)^{2n}\rceil = (\sqrt{3}+1)^{2n}+(1-\sqrt{3})^{2n} (=a_{2n})$ (note that the latter term is positive since it's being raised to an even power, and that $|1-\sqrt{3}|\lt 1$).
3. Show that the sequence $a_n=(\sqrt{3}+1)^{n}+(1-\sqrt{3})^{n}$ satisfies the recurrence relation $a_{n+2} = 2a_{n+1}+2a_n$ with suitable initial conditions.  (This is actually easier to do in the other direction - look up the theory of *linear recurrence relations* for more details.  It's related to the Binet formula for the Fibonacci numbers.)
4. Show by induction using the recurrence relation that the successive $a_n$ are divisible by higher and higher powers of 2.

Comment: you're right. Initially tried to use $\sqrt{3} -1$ which didn't lead to a nice recurrence relation, so I was thrown off by the switch.